# Cannon.js - Collisions with rotating object not as expected

Tags: collision-detection, collision, cannon.js

I am currently using Cannon.js with Three.js to simulate physics, specifically collisions.

I have a rotating 'spinner arm', which constantly spins on its Y axis, using the following code:

`angularVelocity: new CANNON.Vec3(0,5,0)
fixedRotation: true`

I have a method which creates 50 spheres and sets a velocity on each one so they roll into the spinner. When a sphere is hit, it turns red.

The problem is that some of the spheres seem to roll straight through the spinning arm and some have a very small impact which leads to weird results.

Is there something I've missed or need to do differently to make sure all the spheres hit and collide with the spinning arm?

Demo here - https://codepen.io/danlong/pen/LJQYYN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try increasing objects (spheres in this case) size `var sphereShape = new CANNON.Sphere(1);` and world sub-steps count too `this.world.step(1 / 60, 40);` default is 10. When increasing sphere radius don't forget to move them up on `y` axis `let y = 1;`.

Most likely objects are too small and moving fast enough for calculations too become inaccurate.

From performance standpoint it's better to increase objects' sizes rather than sub-steps count. But verify with tests in any case.

Comment: Thanks, increasing the spinner and the sphere size makes a big difference. It doesn't get me the whole way there, but increasing the sub-steps slightly (20) seems to.